# Accessing a nested ng-repeat variable

Tags: angularjs

This is what I have so far:

```
<div ng-repeat="storeSection in main.foodBySection" ng-show="main.sortBy === 'storeSection'">
      <h4>{{ storeSection.category }}</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="ingredient in main.ingredients | orderBy: 'name'"
           ng-if="ingredient.storeSection === {{ storeSection.category }}">
        <p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ingredient.added"/> {{ ingredient.name }} <span
          class="ingredient-source">- {{ ingredient.source }}</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Basically, I only want to display the items in main.ingredients that have the same category as the header, but I cannot access {{ storeSection.category }} once I use a new ng-repeat. Any ideas?

Comment: Why use interpolation? Just use `storeSection.category`, [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) works with an angular expression

Comment: I answered the same thing below, if this solved your question, you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="storeSection in main.foodBySection" ng-show="main.sortBy === 'storeSection'">
      <h4>{{ storeSection.category }}</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="ingredient in main.ingredients | orderBy: 'name'"
           ng-if="ingredient.storeSection === storeSection.category ">
        <p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ingredient.added"/> {{ ingredient.name }} <span
          class="ingredient-source">- {{ ingredient.source }}</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Don't interpolate `storeSection.category`, [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) works with [angular-expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) just like the left-hand operand`ingredient.storeSection` is getting evaluated by it

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="storeSection in main.foodBySection" ng-show="main.sortBy === 'storeSection'">
      <h4>{{ storeSection.category }}</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="ingredient in main.ingredients | orderBy: 'name'"
           ng-if="ingredient.storeSection === storeSection.category">
        <p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ingredient.added"/> {{ ingredient.name }} <span
          class="ingredient-source">- {{ ingredient.source }}</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in another answers, the cause of the problem is that you're using `interpolation` in your `ngIf` directive, which one works with `angular-expressions`.

**Tips:**

Use preferably `ngIf` instead of `ngShow`(in your first `<div>`).

I also recommend you to use the native [**filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead of this check using `ngIf`(in `ngRepeat`) and to use the [**ngRepeat#special-repeats**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat/#special-repeat-start-and-end-points).

So you can have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="storeSection in main.foodBySection" ng-if="main.sortBy === 'storeSection'">
  <h4 ng-bind="storeSection.category"></h4>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="ingredient in main.ingredients | filter: { storeSection: storeSection.category } | orderBy: 'name'">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ingredient.added" /> {{ ingredient.name }} <span class="ingredient-source">- {{ ingredient.source }}</span></p>
</div>
```